# android app crashing when switching activities

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I've been struggling with my application for a while.
I have a maze type game I have created. The main activity starts out with a splash screen that has a small blurb and a button to start the game which just creates a surfaceView on which the sprite and maze is drawn. This is where i encounter my first issue. My app takes up around 50% of the CPU on my phone for some reason. I think it may be because I am drawing rectangles on the screen repeatedly in the onDraw method in my surface view:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
// draws the blocks and the droid sprite
for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
        MapBlock piece = blocks.get(i);
        canvas.drawRect(piece.getBlock(), piece.getColor());
        canvas.drawRect(getRectWithinRect(piece.getBlock()), piece.getInnerRectColor());
    }
    droid.draw(canvas);
}
```

If I move the drawing code or just do it once the maze does not stay on the screen. Is there a better way to do this? I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing it in the right place or not.

My second issue occurs when the user wins. On winning I change the activity using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();         
intent.setClass(getContext(), FinishActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("code", 1);
((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

The switching seems to be working ok. I switch to an activity that simply has some "you won" text and a button to exit.  Here's the only code in the class besides onDestroy and onStop:

```
public class FinishActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d("tga", "made it herE!");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.finish);


}
```

The app crashes when you tap any part of the new screen and the exit button is not responsive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: regarding cpu usage - for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) has the worst performance across all variants. Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html#foreach

Comment: what is this getContext() do, add ur logcat

Comment: Here's my logcat: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=wBKyZ
It's really long so I couldn't post it here but it's all there on the site. Anyone have any ideas? I'm really stuck

Answer (score 0):

insted of

```
intent.putExtra("code", 1);
((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

put this

```
intent.putExtra("code", 1);
((AppCompatActivity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```